# Variance-stabilizing transformation on a simple linear regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, variance, data-transformation, variance-stabilizing

I am currently working with variance-stabilizer method and readed something about it from my textbook. I want to understand it better so I would like to consider a case where I for instance have a simple linear regression, let's say I have a model with response $y$, intercept and explanatory variable $x$, that is,
$$y_k=\beta_0+\beta_1x_k+\epsilon_k, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k=1,...,n.$$
with the residual variance proportional to the square of $x_k$: $V(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2x^2_k$. Then I would take the following as data transformation:
$$\tilde{y}_k:=\frac{y_k}{x_k} \text{ and } \tilde{x_k}:=\frac{1}{x_k}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k=1,...,n.$$
Here is what I don't understand. The first thing is: Can I say something about the above is indeed a variance-stabilizing transformation? Second: Can I say something about the parameters from the models with original or transformed data related
to each other?

I've found examples of variance-stabilizing transformation on wikipedia where they use integrals and so on, but I cannot se how it could be applied in my example. I hope anyone can help me to better understand the variance-stabilizing transformation.

---

Okay so I got more knowledge to my own problem thanks to the readings from another user here. So what I also see that we might be able to use other variance stabilizing transformation. So let's say we know the value of $\beta_0$ which will be a number. I saw something about root transfromation so can I use this or will there be any other better variance stabilizing transformation?

Comment: This is not a transformation at all, because you make each new value of the $y_k$ depend not only on the original value but also on a separate value $x_k.$ At best that makes it a *collection* of transformations (with dubious utility for linear regression).  Consider reviewing some of [our posts on variance stabilizing transformations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=variance%20stabiliz*%20transf*%20score%3a5%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: I would like to say thank you. It make sense. I will read the provided link.

One last question. I see that I can use weighted least squares in this problem with $w_k=1/x_k^2$ but would it equivalent to the above considered transformation? I think yes because we have it on the form $Var(Y_k)=\sigma^2/w_k$. I hope my question makes sense?

Comment: I mean, then we will have $Var(Y_k)=\sigma^2x_k^2$ so I believe that weighted least squares  is indeed equivalent to my problem.

Comment: Hello @whuber. I've tried to read your link regarding variance stabilizing transformations. But I have a question... I know we can consider weighted least squares but can we consider other data transformations of my model assuming that we know $\beta_0$? Can we use root transformation? Best regards

Comment: It depends on the data.  For instance, if some of the values of $y-\beta_0$ are negative, a root transformation wouldn't be possible.  But the spread-vs-level plot allows you to consider *all* Box-Cox transformations and select one or two of them most likely to improve the analysis.  It helps remove the guesswork.

Comment: Ahh! I understand. Thanks man. I will try to read more.